# String.Format and culture

Tags: c#, .net, culture

When formatting a string as opposed to a DateTime, does the culture ever come into play? Are there any examples of strings that would be formatted differently with two different cultures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so in the current Framework.  But if Microsoft ever implements [this suggestion on the Connect feedback site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/93783/more-standard-formatting-options-for-strings#details), it includes a suggestion to have a format specifier to force upper case:

```
String.Format("{0:U}", "SomeString") => "SOMESTRING"
```

Such formatting would be culture-specific.

Comment: The thing you mention is already there. Have a look [TextInfo](http://www.dotnetperls.com/textinfo)

Comment: @Waqas: But it isn't part of String.Format.

Answer (score 3):

If you are displaying a string that is stored as a resource it will make a difference if you have separate strings for different cultures (you'd use CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture). For example error messages accessed via a ResourceManager.

Answer (score 1):

`String.Format("{0}", "This string")` - which I believe is what you're implying by your question, is not affected by the culture.

Answer (score 0):

There are many scenarios when you need culture based formatting.

For example: - **Number Format**

5.25 in English is written as 5,25 in French

So, if you want to display French formatted number in your program which is in English culture the `culture based string format` comes into action.

Comment: @juharr: No, this is right. You format a string to contain a number. The string is the *result* of the formatting, not necessarily the input.

Comment: For this question I am talking about only strings as input.